# has_and_belongs_to_many HABTM fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have this relationship,

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

class Topics < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

I have a pre-defined list of topics stored in a table under **topics** already. Each **article must have 3 topics** associated with it.  If I *create* a new article, how would the code looks from the **controller** and the **view**? What's the most efficient and correct way to create this?

Answer (score 2):

Add three spinner fields to your form and populate them with the topic ids as the data and topic names as the label. Fortunately there are form helpers to do most of the heavy lifting for you. [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects) for details on `collection_select`. Here's an example taken from that link:

```
<%= collection_select(:person, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

In your controller you can create the necessary associations based on the ids selected. It should look something like this:

_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for @article do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= collection_select(:article, :topic_id_1, Topic.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= collection_select(:article, :topic_id_2, Topic.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= collection_select(:article, :topic_id_3, Topic.all, :id, :name) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

acticle_controller.rb

```
def create
  ...
  @article.topics << Topic.find params[:topic_id_1]
  @article.topics << Topic.find params[:topic_id_2]
  @article.topics << Topic.find params[:topic_id_3]
  ...
end
```